# How can I display an image stored as Byte[] in a SQL server database to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

How can I display an image stored as Byte[] in a SQL server database to a DataGridView.

this is the code i used to add the picture :

```
byte[] imgData;
imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);
drow[1] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgData.ToString()) ? DBNull.Value : (object)imgData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DataGridViewImageColumn from displaying images.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.aspx) is the example of it.